# How do I return a variable from a Ruby method?

Tags: ruby

What's the best way to return the value of the 'hash' variable?

```
define_method :hash_count do 
  char_count = 0
  while char_count < 25 do 
    hash = ''
    hash << 'X'
    char_count += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `while 20 < 25` is alwasy true -- you just defined an endless loop.

Comment: However, The result of the last executed expression in a method is the return value. Except when you explicitly call `return` (as in `return hash`).

Comment: I meant 20 > 25! I would like to be able to print 4 'x' to the screen!

Comment: Try `'X' * 4`, this gives you "XXXX"

Comment: It's a looping experiment! I don't have some weird desire to see 4 X' in a line haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `hash` outside the loop. If it's inside you keep resetting it on every iteration.

```
define_method :hash_count do 
  char_count = 0
  hash = ''
  while char_count < 25
    hash << 'X'
    char_count += 1
  end
  hash # returns the hash from the method
end
```

By the way, you don't have to keep track of the `char_count`. Just check the length of the string:

```
define_method :hash_count do 
  hash = ''
  hash << 'X' while hash.length < 25
  hash # returns the hash from the method
end
```

Comment: Because the OP did. It's a correction of the OPs code, not a recommendation of the Ruby-way to do it.